# vertically aligning text and an image (image top to text x-height, image bottom to 7th line baseline)

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I want to achieve the following:

1. Float an image to the left.
2. Align text on the right like this:

   • Top of the image exactly aligned to top of x-height of text

   • Bottom of the image exactly aligned to baseline of the 7th or n-th line.

And these conditions should be satisfied whenever the type size is changed.

Is it possible to do with CSS?

Here is a sample but it does not work for me whatever I try: text-align: top/text-top/super etc:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <img style="height:8em; width:4em;" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="">
</div>

<div style="vertical-align:text-top;">
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.<br />
    This is sample text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's about as close as you can get.

Try setting the line height of the text (using `line-height`) to something reasonable (like `line-height: 1.2em`), and then setting the height of the image to n * line-height (like `height: 8.4em` for 7 lines at 1.2em).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but it does not work. There must be some other way...

Comment: That's the best I can think of without using JS. In the end it might be more efficient to hard-code a pixel or em value.